# Moving space from one partition to another?

Tags: partition, storage

I am really uncertain if this is possible or how I would go about fixing this problem.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             14G   12K   14G   1% /dev
tmpfs           2.8G  388K  2.8G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        30G   26G  2.6G  91% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             14G     0   14G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sdb1       394G   54G  321G  15% /mnt
```

It appears I have sufficient space on `/dev/sdb1` but i don't have enough space on `/dev/sda1`. Is it possible to move gigabytes from sdb1 to sda1?

Comment: can you provide info about what filesystems are mounted on those block devices?  also for sake of couriosity, what are those `**` in `**/dev/sda`

Comment: I just mean to bold that line. They are gone now. How do i go about getting what filesystems are mounted on those block devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **/dev/sdX** ( "X" is a character, e.g. a, b, c...) - this represents a block device (it could be HDD, SSD or other storage device)
- **/dev/sdXN** (`/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` in your **df**-command output) - this represents specific partition on `/dev/sdX` device.

You cannot move "physical" storage space (sectors, GB...) between different storage devices.

> Below information is based on assumptions. Please keep this in mind.

I believe your actual requirement is to have free space in your "/" mount point. You can achieve this in different ways. The most simple is to move part of your data from `/dev/sda1` to `/dev/sdb1`...

In my opinion it is a good idea to **move "user" data from** `/dev/sda1` **to** `/dev/sdb`. Most probably your `/home` directory is located on `/dev/sda1`.

1. Backup your `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` volumes!
2. Use partitioning tool to shrink your `/dev/sdb1`. For example you can use `gparted`. You need to free enough space for your `/home` directory, including your future needs.
3. Add new partition (`/dev/sdb2`). Format it using the same file system type as `/dev/sda1` has. This will ensure that you'll be able store all your data from `/home` correctly (including access rights, etc.). (Actually "almost all" - if your /home contains hardlinks to other files, which are not located in /home you wont be able to keep them as hardlinks. All hardlinks must be placed in one file system.)
4. Copy all your data from your current `/home` directory to `/dev/sdb2`. You may choose different tools, for example - **rsync**, or **cp** (both with appropriate options).
5. Remove all contents from `/home` directory.
6. Mount `/dev/sdb2` on `/home`. You can make your system perform automount during boot. Please see your distribution's documentation for more details.

**ATTENTION: Please remember to backup all your data from /dev/sda and /dev/sdb before any manipulations.**

-- 
UPD: "*How do i go about getting what filesystems are mounted on those block devices?*"
See `blkid`, `mount` or `sudo parted -l` output.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most data is in the home directory (?) Mount `/dev/sdb1` as `/home` partition. Move old `home` to new `home`. (Or change each users home dir with `usermod -d user` to `/mnt/home/user` and move files ...)

Answer (score 0):

Taking the question as written, it's impossible to move gigabytes of space from one *physical* device to another.  The devices being:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda1        30G   26G  2.6G  91% /
/dev/sdb1       394G   54G  321G  15% /mnt
```

...since `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` end with different letters, they are probably distinct physical devices, and it can't be done.

However, one can move *files* from `/dev/sda1` to `/dev/sdb1`.  Suppose `/dev/sda1` contains a 20G file */home/user/foo.bar*.  Executing `mv /home/user/foo.bar /mnt/foo.bar` would make the free space look like this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda1        30G    6G 22.6G  20% /
/dev/sdb1       394G   74G  301G  19% /mnt
```