# Moving space from one partition to another? /dev/nvme0n1 -> /dev/xvda1

Tags: linux, partition, disk-usage, storage

I ran out of space on "/dev/xvda1" and I want to pull some space from either "tmpfs" or "/dev/nvme0n1" into "/dev/xvda1"

```
% df --print-type
Filesystem    Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1    auto    10190104   9319196    749668  93% /
tmpfs        tmpfs    15701132     27684  15673448   1% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1  ext4   913044544  89303860 777337584  11% /local
```

I briefly looked at: [Moving space from one partition to another?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351961/moving-space-from-one-partition-to-another)

But I don't really understand - like I don't see anything named "sda1" or "sdb1"

Comment: While it's not possible to move space from one partition to another, there's a way to simulate that: Using LVM. `/dev/xvda1` is a partition on a Xen virtual disk. `/dev/nvme0n1` is a partition on an SSD drive. With LVM you can create logical volumes (think of these as virtual partitions) which span across multiple partitions (physical volumes). You may need an additional partition to boot from, but LVM can bring your various storage devices and make them appear as one. Except for tmpfs; That's all in RAM.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is: You can't. This is because (as it is already explained in the question and answers you mention) `/dev/xvda1` and `/dev/nvme0n1` are partitions on different devices.

What you can do is to copy (with exact permissions) for example your `/home` directory under `/local` filesystem. Then check again the files, remove `/home` and create softlink. Again, do not try hardlink, it work only in one partition! This will free some space (usually `/home` is one of the most used directories. Other candidates are `/var/log`, `/var/spool`)

If you are uncertain create backup copy of `/home` (or directory you move under `/local`)!

Comment: how do you know they are partitions on different devices? Do you know what type auto means (the other two types are tempfs and ext4)?

Comment: @MichaelLafayette, in the Q/A you mention there is explanation. You can also check the documents about naming convention in linux kernel. So `/dev/xvda` is one device (disk), `/dev/nvme0n` is another device (disk)